# Adding additional node to bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I am trying to modify a beamer.sty file that I am using for a presentation. 
The file at the moment puts a logo in the upper left corner. I want to add one in the upper right corner, too.

```
  \node [shift={(9.5mm,9.5mm)}]  at (current page.north east) 
 {\includegraphics[width=12.8mm]{logo.pdf}};
```

I tried adding this code to put the same image in the upper right corner:

```
  \node [shift={(9.5mm,9.5mm)}]  at (current page.north east) 
 {\includegraphics[width=12.8mm]{logo.pdf}};
  \node  [shift={(9.5mm, 9.5mm)}] at (current page.north west) 
 {\includegraphics[width=12.8mm]{logo.pdf}};
```

But nothing is displayed. I tried playing around with the shift (using -9.5mm, for example, or simple shift = (0, 0)) but the second logo is never displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I never used TikZ :(

Comment: Try `\node [below left] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=12.8mm]{logo}};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wonderful! I had to adjust the shift a bit to make it work but now it's perfect. Thank you! If you make that an answer (maybe elaborating a bit on why it works) I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
\node at (x,y) {foo};
```

the node is placed with its center point at `(x,y)`. For placing a node in the corner of a page, it may be more useful if it is the corner of the node that is placed at the given coordinate.

There are two different ways of doing that, by specifying either the `anchor` of the node, or its position. So,

```
\node [anchor=north east] at (x,y) {foo};
```

or

```
\node [below left] at (x,y) {foo};
```

will both place the node such that its top right corner is located at `(x,y)`.

(Unsurprisingly, there are corresponding anchors for the other seven compass directions, and combinations of `above`/`below`/`left`/`right`.)

In addition, note that by default there is some separation between the content of the node and its border, which you may or may not want/need. The `inner sep` key determines that padding.

Hence, you might want to use

```
\node [below left,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=12.8mm]{logo}};
```